# Yacc %define parse.error verbose generates error

Tags: yacc, lex

When I try to get more out of my "syntax error", I seem to use the way described on so many websites, but all seem to create their own errors, for some reason.

I was getting standard "syntax error" on line 5 of the Input file... so I wanted to add better error handling so I can see what exactly is the issue. But

```
%define parse.error verbose
```

However, it gives me this;

```
error: %define variable 'parse.error' is not used
```

Below are my files, as long as you keep it constructive, feel free to comment on more then just the error parts, any help is welcome :)
(As long as the errors get fixed as well :P )
Thanks in advance!

lex file;

```
%option nounput yylineno
%{
#include "yaccTest.tab.h"
void InvalidToken();
void extern yyerror (char *s);
%}

whitespace      [ \t\r\v\f]
linefeed        \n

%%

";"                     {return SEMICOLON;}
"="                     {return EQ;}
"+"                     {return PLUS;}
"-"                     {return MINUS;}
"*"                     {return MULTIPLY;}
"/"                     {return DEVIDE;}
"("                     {return BO;}
")"                     {return BC;}
"^"                     {return POWER;}

"print"                 {return PRINT;}

[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    {yylval.charValue = yytext[0]; return IDENTIFIER;}
[0-9]+                  {yylval.intValue = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER;}
{whitespace}            {;}
.                       {InvalidToken();}

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
fprintf(stderr, "\nERROR ON LINE %d : \n %s\n", yylineno, s);
exit(0);
}

void InvalidToken(){
printf("ERROR ON LINE %d : \n Invalid Token %s\n", yylineno,yytext);
exit(0);
}

int yywrap (void) {return 1;}
```

yacc file;

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getVariableValue(char varID);
extern int yylineno;
int varIDs[52] = {0};
int varValues[52] = {0};
%}

%define parse.lac full
%define parse.error verbose

%union YYSTYPE {int intValue; char charValue;}

%token COLON SEMICOLON ST SE EQ GE GT PLUS MINUS MULTIPLY DEVIDE BO BC CBO CBC POWER LOOP PRINT
%token <intValue> NUMBER
%token <charValue> IDENTIFIER CHAR

%type <charValue> declaration expression
%type <intValue> numval

%right EQ
%left PLUS MINUS
%left MULTIPLY DEVIDE
%left POWER

%%

declaration : IDENTIFIER EQ expression
| declaration IDENTIFIER EQ expression
;

expression : numval SEMICOLON
| PRINT BO numval BC SEMICOLON              {printf("Printing");}
;

numval : NUMBER                 {$$ = $1;}
| NUMBER PLUS NUMBER        {$$ = $1 + $3;}
| NUMBER MINUS NUMBER       {$$ = $1 - $3;}
| NUMBER MULTIPLY NUMBER    {$$ = $1 * $3;}
| NUMBER DEVIDE NUMBER      {$$ = $1 / $3;}
| NUMBER POWER NUMBER       {int i;int j = $1;for(i = 1; i < $3; i++){j=j*$1;};$$ = j;}
;

%%

int getVariableValue(char varID) {
int i, j, localTemp;
for (i=0;i<((sizeof(varIDs)/sizeof(varIDs[0])));i++) {
    if (varID == varIDs[i]) {
        localTemp = varValues[i];
    }
}
return localTemp;
}

int setVariableValue(char varID, int varValue) {
    int i, varPresent = 0;
    for (i=0;i<((sizeof(varIDs)/sizeof(varIDs[0])));i++) {
        if (varID == varIDs[i]) {
            varValues[i] = varValue;
            varPresent = 1;
        }
    }

    if (varPresent == 0) {
        for (i=0;i<((sizeof(varIDs)/sizeof(varIDs[0])));i++) {
            if (&(varIDs[i]) == NULL) {
                if (&(varValues[i]) == NULL) {
                    varIDs[i] = varID;
                    varValues[i] = varValue;
                }
                else {
                    missingVarIDError(varID, varValue);
                }
            }
            else {
                notEnoughStorageError(varID, varValue);
            }
        }
    }
}

int missingVarIDError(char *id, int val){
printf("\nERROR ON LINE %d : \nIdentifier '%s' not found, but assigned location DOES have a value; %s",yylineno,id,val);
exit(0);
}

int notEnoughStorageError(char *id, int val){
printf("\nERROR ON LINE %d : \nIdentifier '%s' did not fit in StorageArray, '%3' not stored!",yylineno,id,val);
exit(0);
}

int main (void) {
return yyparse ( );
return 0;
}
```

Input file;

```
x=4;
y=2+6;
X=2;
z=5;
print(4);
```

Comment: What is your bison version? You might need to update.

Comment: I am Using Yacc without bison.

Comment: "yacc" does not implement `%define` directives; if you were using the AT&T yacc, it would give you a different error. You are using bison, possibly in yacc compatibility mode (and in that case, it is possible that some bison extensions won't work), but you are definitely using bison

Comment: When I downloaded it, i could choose yacc OR yacc and bison. I choose only yacc, so IDK then :P anyway, how do I find my bison version in that case?

Comment: Use the `--version` flag. Didn't the download source tell you what version you were downloading? And if you want to use bison features, don't use yacc compatibility mode.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to get back to you, I had some deadline to make and no time to play around :P

bison version; 2.4.1
flex version; 2.5.4

I am aware they are not the newest, but it is the only ones that did not confuse me with installation... I am not fond or experienced with manual installs. If I need to manually (instead of run an .exe) to install newer versions, I require more help then I dare to confess xD

Comment: that is a very old bison. Probably verbose errors don't work in that version. I don't have it handy but I'll see if I can find one..

Comment: That would be awesome!

Comment: Yesterday I found this in a Bison 2.7 installation I have to use as long as other Bison 3 installations.